# How to reference ForeignKey objects in HTTP POST?

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, put

I have a RESTful API on Django and I would like to know how to reference an existing ForeignKey when using json in HTTP POST?

```
class Trainer(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='profiles')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=date(2016,7,13), null=True, blank=True)
    faction = models.ForeignKey('Faction', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0, null=True, verbose_name="team")
    has_cheated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_cheated = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    currently_cheats = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    statistics = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    daily_goal = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_goal = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    prefered = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="main profile")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Faction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    colour = RGBColorField(default='#929292', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=factionImagePath, blank=True, null=True)
    leader_name = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    leader_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=leaderImagePath, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This are the relevant models, I have a list of 4 Faction objects, with their primary keys being 0, 1, 2 and 3.

I've tried many different way, but I just can't figure it out. 
This was my latest try, can you advice where I'm going wrong?

```
{
    "username": "Bob123",
    "faction": "1"
}
```

Returned

```
{
    "username": "Bob123",
    "faction": "Teamless",
    "start_date": "2016-07-13",
    "has_cheated": false,
    "last_cheated": null,
    "currently_cheats": false,
    "statistics": true,
    "daily_goal": null,
    "total_goal": null,
    "last_modified": "2017-09-08T21:05:18.001389Z",
    "prefered": true,
    "account": null
}
```

Edit: My friend helped me with the solution, I had `faction = serializers.StringRelatedField()` in the serializer for Trainer, which is Read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me with the solution, I had 1faction = serializers.StringRelatedField()1 in the serializer for Trainer, which is Read-only.